# Two different FS transceivers on point to point link

Tags: cisco, switch, fiber

We have Cisco router with `XFP-10GLR-OC192SR` fiber transceivers and other end we have `10GBASE-SR SFP+` does that work to different capability.

In short one side `LR` and other side `SR` fiber port does that work or i should match them?

Suggestion:

Inside datacenter (short distance) should we go with `SR` or `LR`

Comment: I think those use different wavelengths. See the table in http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/interfaces-modules/transceiver-modules/data_sheet_c78-455693.html

Comment: `SR` (short range) works with MMF, and `LR` (long range) works with SMF, but I think some of the transceivers will work with MMF.

Comment: I think you are right `LR` and `SR` won't work in point to point link

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

SR-based transceiver are designed to work over MMF, and LR-based transceivers are designed to work over SMF. SFP+ MMF is incompatible with SFP+ SMF. And if you want them to work, you should use mode conditioning patch cords on each side. But these cables are often more expensive since they are especially manufactured. So, sometimes it's very important to buy right [transceiver modules](http://www.fs.com/c/fiber-optic-transceivers-9).

Answer (score 0):

What you have isn't right, it may actually link up, but I wouldn't recommend it.  For short distance (less than 300m) inside data center over Multimode optical fiber (MMOF) 10GBASE-SR is what you want.